# How to make a tree out of class that has itself list C#

Tags: c#

```
public class Branch
{
    List<Branch> branches;
}
```

I have this class, and I want to create like a tree thing where this object would have another object and so on, but I can't figure out how to do so or if it is even possible?

Comment: This is already a representation of a tree. Not sure what you mean be "make a tree". Do you mean a visual representation? Then please specify the UI framework to use (WPF, WinForms, ...)

Comment: I'm asking how can I use this class to create an instance of such tree. For example: Branch tree = new(); tree.add(new Branch()); and so on.. @KlausGütter

Comment: So I think You are looking for Composite design pattern
https://www.dofactory.com/net/composite-design-pattern

Comment: `tree.add(new Branch());` - this would be `tree.branches.Add(new Branch());` with your class. Of course, you can add an `Add` method to your class which simplifies this.

Answer (score 0):

You can elaborate a bit your code: if you want to use `Add` (`Remove` etc.) your have to implement them. Let the implementation check the details (if we are trying to make a loop in the tree, adding null etc.) , some service (`Parent`, `Value` as a payload) will be good as well.

**Code:**

```
public class Branch<T> : IReadOnlyList<Branch<T>>
{
    private readonly List<Branch<T>> branches = new List<Branch<T>>();

    public Branch(T? value) {
        Value = value;
    }

    public Branch() : this(default(T)) { }

    public T? Value { get; set; }

    public Branch<T>? Parent { get; private set; }

    public void Add(Branch<T> child) {
        if (child is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(child));

        for (var parent = Parent; parent != null; parent = parent.Parent)
            if (parent == child)
                throw new ArgumentException("No loops in tree!", nameof(child));

        if (child.Parent != null)
            child.Parent.Remove(child);

        branches.Add(child);

        child.Parent = this;
    }

    public bool Remove(Branch<T> child) {
        if (child is null || !ReferenceEquals(child.Parent, this))
            return false;

        branches.Remove(child);
        child.Parent = null;
        return true;
    }

    public int Count => branches.Count;

    public Branch<T> this[int index] => branches[index];

    public IEnumerator<Branch<T>> GetEnumerator() => branches.GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => branches.GetEnumerator();
}
```

Then you can put the tree creation like this:

```
        Branch<int> tree = new Branch<int>(1) {
            new Branch<int>(2) {
                new Branch<int>(3),
                new Branch<int>(4)
            },

            new Branch<int>(5)
        };
```